# angular-ui-router добавление состояния

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

Есть 2 модуля App и AppUsers, в config каждого указаны роуты:

**App:**

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', '/users')
    .otherwise("/404");

$stateProvider
    .state("home", {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    });
```

**AppUsers:**

```
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/users/','/users');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home.users', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/users',
            template: '<div ui-view></div>'
        })

        .state('home.users.list', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'pages/users/list/template.html',
            controller: 'UsersListCtrl',
        })

        .state('home.users.view', {
            url: '/view?user',
            templateUrl: 'pages/users/user_view/template.html',
            controller: 'UserViewCtrl',
            resolve: {
                user: ['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
                    return $scope.userList[$stateParams.user];
                }]
            }
        });
```

При попытке перейти на `/users/view?user=someID` редиректит на `/users`

Comment: По идее все правильно. Я бы ради проверки немного поменял пути, сделал для `.state('home.users.list'` путь `url: '/list'` а для `.state('home.users.view'` - `url: '/:user'`

Comment: в том то и дело, что нужно через query params ...

Comment: Сделал для проверки - не работает =/

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден, нужно просто убрать

```
resolve: {
  user: ['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
            return $scope.userList[$stateParams.user];
  }]
}
```

Но теперь возникает новый вопрос, как подготовить данные перед компиляцией вьюхи?

Comment: Новый вопрос стоит задать в виде нового вопроса. Тут его никто не заметит.

Comment: Может я что-то путаю, но по моему значением в мапе резолва должна быть строка или функция, а не массив, и возвращать он должен промис.

Comment: Использовать можно в родительском роуте ... https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha